# WebStorm 11.0.4 has issues with debugging. It gives a deprecated warning that node --debug and node --debug-brk are invalid

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ide, webstorm

**Exact warning:**

> DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

**Node version:** 8.9.3

Is there a workaround to trick the IDE to debug seamlessly?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Warning is correct - those keys/params are deprecated for Node v8 (maybe even v7 -- not sure as I'm not a node person myself). Solution: upgrade IDE to the latest version -- there were 6 releases after your version. Latest stable is 2017.3.3

Answer (score 2):

Please upgrade WebStorm to 2017.3.x - WebStorm 11 provides no support for Node 8, you won't be able to debug, configure Node.js Core library, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Isn't there a workaround? With 11.x

Comment: Downgrading Node.js to 4.x is the only workaround for WebStorm 11. Debugging with Node.js 6, 7, 8. 9 won't work